# ORA-22806: not an object or REF when use json path item function

Tags: sql, json, oracle

The error "ORA-22806: not an object or REF" was reported when I run the following sql in oracle 21c.

```
create table t(j json);
insert into t values('{"k": "v"}');
select t.j.type() from t t;
```

```
SQL> select t.j.type() from t t;
select t.j.type() from t t
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22806: not an object or REF
```

but this's success;

```
select t.j.k.type() from t t;
```

I can not understand why this error was occured, can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you expect the first version that gives an error to return?

Comment: @gsalem You would expect it to return `object` as that is the type of the JSON element at the root.

Comment: well, from the description [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-8656CAB9-C293-4A99-BB62-F38F3CFC4C13), it seems to apply to 'items' of a json column, or functions json_value, json_table and json_query. Not clear if it will be considered a bug by Oracle dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE(j, '$.type()') FROM t;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zrnp5uxn)

> I can not understand why this error was occurred, can anyone help me?

`t.j` is the identifier for the column, and you have not yet descended into the JSON structure, so when you call `t.j.type()` the SQL engine assumes that `t.j` will be an SQL object with the `type` method (or a reference to an object with that method) and it appears that it does not switch to parsing the JSON and find the `type` method within the JSON parser.

This could probably be classified as a bug with the JSON implementation but you can get around it by using `JSON_VALUE` as shown above.